# Power supply of board based on tp4056 with protection gives too low voltage

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, pcb-design, charger

I have a project on small pocket board with a Li-Ion battery so I made a pcb with power section based on a tp4056 board (with protection), with LP2985IM5X-3.3 stabilizer. TP4056 charges the Li-ion and it works good, on the out I have 3.6V, but when I turn on the stabilizer before it is 0.6V and next to it is ~0.2 - 0.6V. I have no idea how to fix it to work on the 3.3V level. Please, write to me some suggestions. Thanks.

Schematic of power section:
[image]

## Edit:

I changed MOSFETs connection (look comments) and voltage is fine, everything works good but there is one problem, it doesn't charge li-ion.

Comment: How much current are you trying to draw from the regulator?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm going to get max 100mA. PS: I tried this only with microcontroller, maybe it is to low current and regulator donot work good ?

Comment: That regulator should be fine down to single-digit mA.

Comment: Ok. My mistake. MOSFET A should go to pin 1 and MOSFET B to pin 3. Now voltage is correct. But there is another problem, it doesn't charge li-ion